# JSON Serialize Object Array Android

Tags: android, json

I have a very simple Object Array

```
Object[] args = new Object[] {"002"};
```

My goal is to JSON serialize this Object Array in Android and get the result as a byte array. There are two classes for JSON Serialization in Android. `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`. Which class should I use?

Spefically I am not sure how to use the

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("key", "value");
```

routine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a JSONArray for this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put("002");
byte[] bytes = jsonArray.toString().getBytes()
```

Comment: can I also do  jsonArray.put(new Object[] {"002"}); would it have the same effect?

Comment: No, see the description on the value parameter here for the allowed arghements [linl](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#put(int, java.lang.Object))

Comment: You can however pass an Object array containing just boxed primitives or Strings as an argument to the constructor of JSONArray(). `new JSONArray(new Object[]{"002"}).toString()` would result in `["002"]`